# Decode unicode escape characters with perl

Tags: perl, unicode

I hate to ask a question that's undoubtedly been answered a dozen times before, but I find encoding issues confusing and am having a hard time matching up other people's q/a with my own problem.

I'm pulling information from a json file online, and my perl script isn't handling unicode escape characters properly.

Script looks like this:

```
use LWP::Simple;
use JSON;
my $url = ______;
my $json = get($url);
my $data = decode_json($json);
foreach my $i (0 .. $#{data->{People}}) {
   print "$data->{People}[$i]{first_name} $data->{People}[$i]{last_name}\n";
}
```

It encounters jsons that look like this: `"first_name":"F\u00e9lix","last_name":"Cat"` and prints them like this: `FΘlix Cat`

I'm sure there's a trivial fix here, but I'm stumped. I'd really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: It should work fine if you add `binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";` (provided your output terminal expects UTF8 encoded data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't tell Perl how to encode the output. You need to add

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(XXX)';
```

where `XXX` is the encoding the terminal expects.

On unix boxes, you normally need

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

On Windows boxes, you normally need

```
use Win32 qw( );
use open ':std', ':encoding(cp'.Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP().')';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd found the first recommendation, and it wasn't fixing anything for my on my Windows box, and I was dead stumped. I really appreciate the help. :)