# Strawberry perl gives me a "Wide character in print" when writing to a UTF-8 file

Tags: perl, utf-8, strawberry-perl

I'm running a script in Strawberry perl that reads a file and does some processing and writes the output to another file. I get this message sometimes when it seems to be encountering some non ASCII characters (extended) in the original file.

`Wide character in print at cv2pf.pl line 348, <$fh> chunk 1307`

What's the implication and how do I fix it? It doesn't appear to be having any effects on output file unless I'm missing something.

The solution given here:
[Decode unicode escape characters with perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515013/decode-unicode-escape-characters-with-perl) does NOT solve the problem. I'm writing the output to a file and NOT a console hence the solution doesn't work.

I've specified UTF-8 while opening the file but it's still giving the error

```
# Detect the file type UTF-8 or not
if (!open(READ,$sourcefile))
{
    print "Error: Could not open $sourcefile for detecting.\n";
    next;
}
my $line = <READ>;
my $enc = Encode::Detect::Detector::detect($line);
print "File encoding: $enc\n";
close READ;

if ($enc eq "UTF-8")
{
    if (!open(READ,'<:encoding(UTF-8)',$sourcefile))
    {
        print "Error: Could not open UTF-8 $sourcefile for reading.\n";
        next;
    }
}
else
{
    if (!open(READ,$sourcefile))
    {
        print "Error: Could not open $sourcefile for reading.\n";
        next;
    }
}

if (!open($fh,"+>:encoding(utf8)","$base.m.csv"))
{
    print "Error: Could not open $base.m.csv for reading/writing.\n";
    next;
}

undef $/;
$_=<READ>;
# remove the BOM
if ($enc eq "UTF-8")
{
    $_ =~ s/\x{FEFF}//g;
}
# convert unix line ending to dos
$_ =~ s/\r?\n|\r/\r\n/g;
print $fh $_;
close READ;

$/ = "\r\n";
seek ($fh,0,0);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { allow_whitespace => 1, binary => 1 } );  # should set binary attribute.
```

In the output I'm seeing that the source file is UTF-8 and correspondingly being opened as a UTF-8 file.

> File encoding: UTF-8

What am I missing here?

Other pieces of code as requested:

Line 348

`print {$handles{$currency}} "P" . $row->{'Name'} . "\r\n";`

```
my %handles;
curcheck: while ( $row = $csv->getline_hr( $fh ) ) {
    my $currency=$row->{'Currency'};
    if (exists $handles{$currency}) {
        next curcheck;
    }
    $handles{$currency}=return_fh();
    if (!open($handles{$currency},">:encoding(utf8)","$base-$currency.out"))
    {
        print "Error: Could not open $base-$currency.out for writing.\n";
        next file;
    }

    binmode($handles{$currency})
}
seek ($fh,0,0);
$row = $csv->getline ($fh);


...

sub return_fh {
    local *FH;
    return *FH;
}
```

Comment: Essentially, you've tried to print a "wide" (non-ASCII) character without specifying how such characters should be encoded. If the output appears as you want it then it's probably expecting UTF-8 encoding, and you should add `use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /` which will indicate to perl that stdin, stdout, and stderr, and any newly-opened file handle, all use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: That's correct, the output is as expected but your solution didn't work. It's still throwing an error. Do note that the output is being written to a file and not the console

Comment: What does your output `open` call look like, if there is one? Does it have a mode specified? Do you have a `binmode` call anywhere?

Comment: Just posted the whole code

Comment: Since the error is at line 348, that can't be the whole code. Is line 348 within what you've posted? Which line is it? Are you using `Text::CSV` to write to your output file? Please show that code.

Comment: I can't post the whole code but here is line 348 `print {$handles{$currency}} "P" . $row->{'Name'} . "\r\n";`, yes I'm using `Text::CSV`

Comment: Okay, but why tell me you'd *"Just posted the whole code"*? And where do you open `$handles{$currency}`. Please don't turn this into a guessing game. You need to reduce your code to something you *can* post that shows the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I posted the code related to file opening/reading/writing. Not trying to make you guess, working as best as I can through this. I will update the code above to include the handles code.

Comment: Yes to answer your question earlier, there is binmode being used and I've updated the code to show it. Does that impact it?

Comment: Yes, it does. Remove the `binmode` call and it will work. You're setting your file handles to *UTF-8 encoded* when you open them, and then using `binmode` to change that to *unencoded*. Your `return_fh` is also very weird, and you should be using *lexical file handles* throughout instead of global ones. You've got one `open $fh, ...` which is correct, but should be `open my $fh, ...`. But at least remove `return_fh` and the call to it. `open $handles{$currency} ... ` will work just fine without it. You also need `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of your program.

Comment: There's also no BOM on UTF-8 files.

Comment: Genius, thanks that worked and appreciate the other tips. If you reopen the ticket I'll be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: @Borodin one thing, now the output file contains Ctrl-M characters after each line, how do I get rid of that?

Comment: Are you serious? You remove the line commented `convert unix line ending to dos` that puts them in. Do you actually know any Perl?

Comment: Ignore, found my mistake and it wasn't that, that was for reading the file. The error was in line 348, I'm literally writing it there. Somehow binmode was overriding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging it turns out that the error is because you are explicitly opening a hash of file handles with an explicit mode of `:encoding(utf8)` and then changing that immediately to *unencoded* using `binmode`

The following are also very important for any Perl program

- Start your code with `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`
- Declare all your variables as close as possible to their first point of use; usually when they are defined
- Use *lexical file handles* instead of global ones. For instance

  ```
  unless ( open my $read, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $sourcefile ) {
      print "Error: Could not open UTF-8 $sourcefile for reading.\n";
      next;
  }
  ```

  They are much simpler to pass as subroutine parameters. and Perl will close the automatically when they go out of scope
- Use `$var = undef` instead of `undef $var` to set a variable to `undef`. And use `local $/` to do that temporarily to a global variable, together with a code block `{ ... }` to limit the scope of the change

Answer (score -1):

The solution is `use open` with a proper encoding layer. The fact that you are writing to a file instead of STDOUT doesn't change anything.

```
# Add encoding layer to STD*
use Win32 qw( );
use open ':std', ':encoding(cp'.Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP().')';

# Set default encoding layer for files open in scope of this.
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)';

open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");
```